# IIS application gets error "Loading managed Windows PowerShell failed with error 80070005" executing powershell, but other app on same host works?

Tags: powershell, iis, permissions

I have two web apps hosted on the same Windows 2012 R2 server (an AWS EC2 instance). IIS version 8.5.9600.16384.

Both web apps call the same library function to execute the same Powershell script file on the C: drive. Both web apps' app pools run under Network Service.

However, only web app A is able to successfully execute the Powershell script. Web app B hit the following error when executing that same script:

```
I n t e r n a l   W i n d o w s   P o w e r S h e l l   e r r o r .    L o a d i n g   m a n a g e d   W i n d o w s   P o w e r S h e l l   f a i l e d   w i t h   e r r o r   8 0 0 7 0 0 0 5 .
```

**80070005** suggests a permissions problem.

I have tried the following without luck:

1. Have web app B use the same app pool as web app A
2. Run procmon.exe and compared entries generated by both A and B and found no difference. Both A and B have "process start" events for the script that returned "SUCCESS" status. No "ACCESS DENIED" error found.

Example of such "SUCCESS" event which failed in the end:

```
Event Class:    Process Operation:  Process Start Event Class:  Process Operation:  Process Start Result:   SUCCESS Path:    TID:   3568 Duration:  0.0000000 Parent PID:   1748 Command line:  "powershell.exe" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file "C:\scripts\dostuff.ps1" -arg1 "sometext" Current directory:    c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\
```

What could cause this permissions problem with executing Powershell?

Comment: which kind of application you are using? could you share the sample code to reproduce the issue and detailed error message? you could use the process monitor to check which for the which is user trying to access the PowerShell so can assign right permission.[Solving Access Denied Errors Using Process Monitor](https://improve.dk/solving-access-denied-errors-using-process-monitor/)  and [download link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal sorry I forgot about this question. I found a way to workaround it, which is to use LocalSystem instead of Network Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to workaround it, which is to use LocalSystem instead of Network Service.